# Rails render redundant key-value pair JSON

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to render a JSON in the format, in my rails application

```
[
    { "name": "Kenneth Auchenberg" },
    { "name": "Jon Froda" }
]
```

I have tried,

```
render json: User.pluck(:username)
```

which renders me something like ["xsdf","yasdf"]. How to render a key-value pair , where the keys are redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pluck` returns you an `Array`, so that is why you have an `Array` as the output.

Try:

```
json = User.pluck(:username).map { |username| { name: username } }
render json: json
```

Comment: Thanks. You saved me hours of stress. _/\_